# What font does the Blender UI use?

Tags: interface

I am trying to recreate a blender menu inside a project, and I want to match the fonts. I have done a lot of research, but a lot of the results just tell me how to add fonts to Blender and not what the original font is. Does anyone know which font Blender uses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The base font is "bfont" which is a form of "Bitstream Vera" fonts that have been modified into a "Deja_Vu" collection to work better with unicode.

Comment: Amazing! How did you find it?

Comment: I can't remember. I had some reason in the past to try and replicate "bfont" properties, so I know it from when I looked it up then. I still have the font file on my PC, surprisingly. You can get it here if you want - https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/dejavu-sans